# "No such partitition" in grub rescue after uninstalling Ubuntu from dual-boot

Tags: grubrescue

I had dual-boot Win7 / Ubuntu and I decided to uninstall Ubuntu with Wubi in the Windows "Programs and Feature".
After the restart I got the message:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode
```

The `ls` command lists:

```
(hd0) (hd0, msdos5) (hd0, msdos4) (hd0, msdos3) (hd0, msdos1)
```

Almost whatever command I try with the partitions, I get `Filesystem is unknown`. I cannot get into BIOS and I've tried boot discs with WinXP, couple of Win7 versions and USB with Ubuntu. Nothing works.

I've tried :

```
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos2)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub # or wherever grub is installed
grub rescue > insmod normal # if this produced an error, reset root and prefix to something else ..
grub rescue > normal
```

but it says `no such partition` after `insmod` command.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing BIOS depends on your specific computer. The key to do that is usually shown during boot (POST). 
Either change the boot order or use the one time boot key to boot from **Windows 7 installation media** (DVD?) and follow instructions in recovery.

Usually `fixmbr` in the recovery console is enough.

PS - Do not use WUBI. If you want a **real** dual boot reserve unallocated space for Ubuntu, boot from its installation media and install normally.

Comment: sorry for taking long to reply, but i've been on a holiday...
"fixmbr" commad is unknown... i've got the preinstalled windows with the laptop and no DVD with it.
i've tried all the combinations to enter BIOS but none of them works (Lenovo laptop).

Thanks for the Wubi advice, but now it's too late :D

Comment: I'll be brutally honest: Why can't you read what's in the screen in front of you each time you turn on the notebook? It says exactly what key or keys to press... Also Lenovos used to come with a special blue key just for that. And fixmbr is available when you boot from Windows installation or recovery media only. Anyway that, obviously, is a Windows question, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I've only attended writting classes so I can't read that fast to see what's on the initial screen....*sigh* The boot screen doesn't show up. And I've tried all the Lenovo combination for entering BIOS or change boot settings. And my Lenovo doesn't have the blue key. 
`fixmbr` is not working, as I have already stated. Since Windows do not use GRUB - it must be a linux thing...
Is there anyone with a constructive comment? Thanks in advance!